# How to expand /boot partition on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partition, root

Recently I made a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop after erasing everything. I have got notification from update manager to update my system. But I am getting the below error which says the size of '/boot' partition needs to be increased.

> The upgrade needs a total of 90.1 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please
>   free at least an additional 2,999 k of disk space on '/boot'. Empty
>   your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using
>   'sudo apt-get clean'.

Now please suggest me ways on how to increase the size of '/boot' partition. See it's on primary partition as shown in the screen shot below.
[image]

Is it a method that I reduce '/home' with say 300 MB and mount this new partition on a directory under '/boot'? Will it work? No I don't think so because while installing at the time of updating via software updater, the system can install anywhere and at many places under /boot. Isn't it? So, it shouldn't work. Also, I wouldn't prefer mounting on '/boot' any partition from extended partition. As my '/boot' is on primary parition, I would prefer it to be completely on primary partition.

Now the only way striking my mind is to shrink the adjacent partition i.e. '/' (root partition) from the start point of the partition and add it in '/boot'. For that I have to boot using live usb drive. So, as my system has separate '/boot' and '/' partitions, so I think shrinking the root partition from the start point may not create any problem while rebooting!
What you say please?

Comment: Commenting rather than providing an answer because this can help but does not answer the actual question - usually, a "sudo apt-get autoremove" will remove older versions of the kernel and related files in /boot, freeing up the space you need without having to expand the partition. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest to do would be to boot a [gparted Live CD/DVD/USB](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), shrink the `/` partition by 800MB, move it to the right and then extend the `/boot` to 1 GB total.

Furthermore, there are reasons to have a separate `/boot` partition but looking at the kind of questions you're asking, next time you re-install, make the `/boot`, `/tmp` and `/var` part of your `/`.  This will allow less hassle and you won't run out of disk space on important directories...  **;-)**

Comment: Won't there be any problem while booting as 1st sector of root partition is moved?

Comment: No, the `/boot` partition is extended: not moved.  The `/` partition is moved.  And neither of these affect the MBR anyway (Which I assume you're using as I can't see an EFI partition.)

Comment: Great Fabby, my system has successfully rebooted & working properly.

Comment: @Ravi: thank you and favour returned: Q upvoted!