# Will booting the system get affected if root partition moved, though boot partition is separate

Tags: boot, move

I need to move the root partition to the right after shrinking it. I have separate boot partition as seen below.
[image]

The free space I want to allocate to boot partition so as to increase it's size. I've a related thread [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247690?noredirect=1).

As my root partition will be moved, will it affect my system booting? I think no as I have a separate boot partition.